# Unable to public a string

Tags: java, android

I want to call a string in a different class but I am unable to make it public it's showing
**Modifier 'public' not allowed here**.

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        switch (event.getEventType()) {
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED:

                String string = event.getText().toString();
```

I want to call the string in a different class in onStartCommand method as for *if* statement
kindly guide me on how can I call the strig without public, or any other method to achieve it.

Comment: You can't make method local variables `public` and visible to the outside. You need to turn it into an instance variable

Comment: That variable **does not exist** except when executing that specific method. and even then only after having executed the particular case.  (Also: terminology nit - you don't "call" strings or other data; you only call methods).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put the declaration `public String string;` outside your method (for example right beneath your class declaration).
You can also declare it private (in the same position though) and add a public getter method:

```
public String getString() {
    return string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make him public, because you're declaring him inside block of code of a method.
So declare the variable string as global variable then your can make it public and using it in another classes.
Like this :

```
public String string;
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    switch (event.getEventType()) {
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED:

            string = event.getText().toString();
```